# PHP::MongoCollection->aggregate() Failures

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB query that is verified as 100% working ( Using MongoHub I have connected to the Replica Set and run the query and received results ), but when converting this query to PHP and attempting to run it through MongoCollection->aggregate(), I fail to get a return/result of any kind whatsoever ... not even an error.

Here is the query, as put into a PHP Array ( as MongoCollection requires ):

```
$query = array(
    '$match' => array(
        '$and' => array(
            'make' => $props[0],
            'model' => $props[1],
            'makeYear' => (integer)$props[2],
            'status' => 'Active'
        )
    ),
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => null,
        'marketTotal' => array('$sum' => '$price'),
        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
    )
);
```

The code to run the query is a simple one-liner calling aggregate.

As I don't get errors ... or a log showing any sort of error ... I'm kind of at a total loss here. Is anyone familiar with using PHP w/ MongoDB able to see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was simply missing a layer of arrays ... wrapping each piece of the '$and' array in its own array ... so array('make' => $props[0]), etc ... made it work.

Fun stuff. MongoDB queries are easy. Translating them into PHP-compatible arrays is apparently very difficult and requires a lot of guesswork because it's not 1-to-1